# Infinite multiplication questions

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that randomly generates two single digit numbers, creates a multiplication question, asks the user for the answer, counts the amount of questions and correct answers, and after every question the user is able to stop the loop to see how many he got correct out of the number of questions that were given.

I believe that I should be using a while loop (probably the easiest way) but I don't know exactly how to go about doing that. Here is what I currently have:

```
    int number = 0;
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10); //Produce two single digit numbers
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Create Scanner

    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + "? "); 

    int answer = input.nextInt();
    while (number <= 10) {
        if (number1 + number2 != answer ) {
        System.out.println(" Incorrect!\n Would you like to see your overall result? (yes or no)");

    }

            else {
            System.out.println(" Correct, great job!\n Would you like to see your overall result? (yes or no)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks in the right direction.  Are you asking us to finish the assignment for you?

Comment: No, not so much doing it for me. I just need some advice on what to do next or if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Yes, you have problems.  Currently, your `while` loop is infinite.  Instead, you should break if the user guessed right, otherwise maybe tell the user his answer is wrong and ask if he wants to guess again.  The scanner read should probably be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems like an assignment I'll just give you pseudocode

```
MainMethod
    {
        //Create a new Random to generate random numbers
        //(Import java.util.random)
        //You need variables for:
        //Total number of questions asked
        //Total number of correct answers
        //Start the question loop
        while(true){
            //Generate your two random numbers
            //Ask the question
            //Index the total number of questions
            //Get their answer
            //Check their answer
            if(answer is correct){
                //Index correct answers
            }
            //Ask whether they want to continue
            //Check whether they want to stop
            if(they want to quit){
                //Break out of the while loop (break;)
            }
        }
        //Tell them how many they got correct out of the total
    }
```

Maybe I gave a little too much, but I hope this helps.